# RSVP an event option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

So i want an option that lets users make an rsvp for a specific event. The event should also have a list of people who already rsvped for the event.
I've tried countless hours to figure this out and read some tutorials I thought were relevant but to no success. I'm not sure how much code I would need to show in this post so I'll just link my github. https://github.com/minhajahmed1/events_platform

I would really appreciate the help and I'm not asking for any of you to complete the code for me, it would really be helpful to me to learn the concept of it by looking at your guys solutions who are far more experienced than me in rails.

Comment: using a gem for rsvp feature would make it easier and require less code I think. did you try any gem ?

even using custom code I don't think it is going to be that complex

Comment: Just as a heads up: linking to your GitHub is probably not going to go over well with the community. You're asking someone to dedicate a lot of time to helping you, when you yourself aren't willing to dedicate the time to helping them out as much as you can so you can get your answer. I know it can be frustrating when you're stuck and don't understand a concept so you don't know what you would share. In this case, as an example, you should have shared your `User` and `Post` model files and described the feature you are trying to implement. That could go a long way. Any bit of detail helps.

Comment: thank you I will remember that for the future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An RSVP is essentially the thing that creates an association between a person and an event in real life. Similarly, in your code, it's how you will link the two models together.

So, to do that, RSVP should be a join table between Users and Events. From looking at your code, you don't seem to have an `Event` model, so I'm assuming for your situation an `Event` is the same thing as a `Post`

So you would do something like this:

**Rsvp.rb**

```
class Rsvp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Then create the associations:

**User.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rsvps
  has_many :posts, through: :rsvps
end
```

**Post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rsvps
  has_many :users, through: :rsvps
end
```

Then create the relevant migration:

```
class CreateRsvps < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :rsvps do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user
      t.belongs_to :post
    end
  end
end
```

Now you can RSVP to an event by doing this:

```
Rsvp.create(user_id: user_id, post_id: post_id)
```

If you want a list of all the events a user is going to, you can do this:

```
user.posts
```

or a list of all the people who have RSVP'd to an event:

```
post.users
```

Comment: I really appreciate all the effort you put into helping me. Where exactly do I put the last 3 lines of code you posted, I understood everything else but the last 3. Where will I be posting this? I do really appreciate your help and you explained it so concisely that even I understood the concept.

Comment: An `Rsvp` a class, so for one to exist (much like with `User` and `Post`), you have to create it. If a user clicks a button to RSVP,  you would trigger that line of code via a form when you click (kind of like login). As for the other two, they are commands.`user` above is just a variable that contains instance of a `User`. If you want to show all of the events a user has RSVP'd to, you would need their instance of `user`, then you call `posts` to find their events. `user.posts` will return a collection of objects (in this case, events) so you can display them on a web page.